# Django adding eventlistener to a for...loop on template tag

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, dom-events

I'm trying to add a event listener to a list of links created by django template tag.

It should take the list of objects with class  `div.cat-link` and add an eventlistener to each one to display the matching id of  `div.cat-select`

html

```html
<div class="cat">
    <div class="cat-links">
        {% for t in tags %}
        <div id="{{t|lower}}" class="cat-link">
            <a class="cat" href="{% url 'list_product1' t %}">{{t}}</a>
        </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="cat-list">
    {% for t in tags %}
    <div class="cat-select" id="cat_{{t|lower}}">
        {% for p in t.produto_set.all %}
        <div class="cat-product">
            <!--IMAGES-->
            <div class='img'>
                <amp-carousel lightbox controls autoplay delay="3000" width="250"
                    height="250" layout="responsive" type="slides">
                    {% for pic in p.images.all %}
                    <amp-img src="{{ pic.image.url }}" width="250" height="150"
                        layout="responsive" alt="{{ p.nome }}">
                    </amp-img>
                    {% endfor %}
                </amp-carousel>
            </div>
            <!-- INFOS -->
            <div class='infos-prod'>
                <a class='cat-product' href="{% url 'detail_product' p.id %}">
                    <h3>{{p.nome}} </h3>
                </a>
                <a class='cat-product' href="{% url 'detail_product' p.id %}">
                    R$: {{ p.preco }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```javascript
<script id="cat-script" type="text/javascript" target="amp-script">

    function Showing(one) {
        var v1 = document.getElementById(one);
        v1.style.display = "flex";

    };
    function Hiding(one) {
        var v1 = document.getElementById(one);
        v1.style.display = "none";

    };


    function Category() {
        var v1 = document.getElementsByClassName('cat-link');
        for (o in v1) {
            var v2 = 'cat_' + v1[o].getAttribute('id')
            v1[o].addEventListener('mouseover', function () { Showing(v2) });
            v1[o].addEventListener('mouseout', function () { Hiding(v2) });
        };
    };

    Category()

</script>
```

It should take the list of objects with class  `div.cat-link` and add an eventlistener to each one to display the matching id of  `div.cat-select`

I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: v1[o].getAttribute is not a function

and nothing is happening.

Comment: Don't use `for...in` on an HTMLCollection. If you log `o` to the console in your loop, you'll see why (o is sometimes `length`, `item`, `namedItem`). `for (let o of v1) { let v2 = 'cat_' + o.id;` should work better. (note: `let`, not `var`, to make sure the scope is preserved in the event handler)

Comment: i't worked great!!. Thanks so much @blex. any JS tutorial you sir would recommend, besides doccumentation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing up Python syntax with JavaScript.

First, try `for (let o of v1)` instead of `for (o in v1)`.

Then, you're trying to access it by index, but that's not the kind of loop you're using. Try `o.getAttribute('id')`.

Comment: i tried with var and let. i'm accessing by the index because when i try to get just by ```o``` it returns me the index of that object inside a HTMLCollection. i  don't understand why untill now. but thanks for the answer